# Mock / create_autospec: verify argument types

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

In a unit test with mocked function, I would like to verify not only the count of arguments, but  also that those conform the declared types of autospec-mocked function.

Here is the example code:

```
from unittest.mock import create_autospec


def foo(a: int, b: str):
    return str(a) + b

mock_foo = create_autospec(foo)

foo = mock_foo  # would be patched by e.g. @patch or monkeypatch fixture
foo(1, 2)
assert foo.called
```

This code tests that `foo` is called correctly. e.g. such call would  fail: `foo(1,2,3)`  This includes validation of arguments, but not of their  types. Is there  a way for autospec or another function to validate the types of passed  arguments? This information is available in the signature of the method, so I imagine I could write myself such a validation using `inspect` module. But is there something standard, a built-in or library?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean - you already know that the arguments are correct, now you want to test if 1 (in your example) is of `int` type? Or do you want to check _only_ the type?

Comment: note that I have called foo with incorrect types of arguments, but this "test" passed.

Comment: Actually I didn't notice :) My point was, if you check for the correct arguments using `assert_called_with`, the correct type is implied - I'm just not sure what your use case is. As Python does not enforce a type outside of tools like `mypy`, I don't think there is a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding a side_effect to your mock that compares arguments and annotations:

```
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

def check_params(method):
    def cp(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg, typ in zip(args, method.__annotations__.values()):
            assert isinstance(arg, typ)
        for k, v in kwargs.values():
            assert isinstance(v, method.__annotations__[k])
    return cp

def foo(a: int, b: str):
    return str(a) + b

mock_foo = create_autospec(foo)
mock_foo.side_effect=check_params(foo)

foo = mock_foo  # would be patched by e.g. @patch or monkeypatch fixture
foo(1, 2)
assert foo.called
```

This will raise an AssertionError because `b` should be a `str` but is an `int`.

This could also be used with a class:
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

```
def check_params(method):
    def cp(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg, typ in zip(args, method.__annotations__.values()):
            assert isinstance(arg, typ)
        for k, v in kwargs.values():
            assert isinstance(v, method.__annotations__[k])
    return cp

class Foo:
    def foo(a: int, b: str):
        return str(a) + b

mock_foo = create_autospec(Foo)
mock_foo.foo.side_effect=check_params(Foo.foo)

mock_foo.foo(1, 2)
assert mock_foo.foo.called
```